# Parsing an arbitrary date/time with moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, momentjs

I am extracting a date from an email (in many possible formats) and then passing it to an app that expects ISO format. I'm told I can use moment.js to parse a date in various formats.

```
Found: 1/22/2016
Milliseconds: 1453449600000
ISO: Fri Jan 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

Found: Jan 22 2016
Milliseconds: 1453449600000
ISO: Fri Jan 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

Found: 2016/1/22 03:00
Milliseconds: 1453460400000
ISO: Fri Jan 22 2016 03:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

How do I use moment to parse all of these formats and more?

```
var foundDue = taskNote.match(/(Deadline|Due):.*(\n|$)/ig);
// if we've found a deadline date...
if (foundDue) {
    // Remove deadline/due tag
    foundDue = foundDue[0].replace(/(Deadline|Due):? */i, "");
    // Remove trailing and leading spaces
    foundDue = foundDue.replace(/(^\s*|\s$)*/, "");
    console.log("Found: "+ foundDue);
    // Use a magic method to parse date
    milliseconds = moment.??????(foundDue);
    console.log("Milliseconds: "+ milliseconds);
    console.log("Parsed2: "+ new Date(foundDue));
    var taskDue = new Date(milliseconds);
    console.log("ISO: "+ taskDue);
}
```

Note, this question is adapted from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183822/parsing-an-arbitrary-date-in-javascript-vs-google-apps-script?noredirect=1#comment67850258_40183822).

Comment: Your example of `1/22/2016` is unambiguous, but what if the date in the email is `1/2/2016` - how do you know if it is 1 Feb or 2 Jan?

Comment: Maybe [chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono) is for you? Other than that, please know that different environments parse Dates differently. Firefox doesnt understand `Date.parse('January 2020')`, but v8 (Chrome etc) does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment parsing with multiple formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) to convert your input strings into moment objects, then you can use moment [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) to get milliseconds.

Here an example snippet for the inputs given in your question:

```js
var inputs = ['1/22/2016', 'Jan 22 2016', '2016/1/22 03:00'];

for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
  var m = moment(inputs[i], ['M/D/YYYY', 'MMM D YYYY', 'YYYY/M/D HH:mm']);
  console.log(m.format(), m.valueOf());
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Note** that, as the docs says, when using multiple formats:

> Moment uses some simple heuristics to determine which format to use. In order:
>
> - Prefer formats resulting in valid dates over invalid ones.
> - Prefer formats that parse more of the string than less and use more of the format than less, i.e. prefer stricter parsing.
> - Prefer formats earlier in the array than later.

In the code sample above, **ambiguous** inputs like `01/02/2016` will always be parsed as `January 2nd 2016`.